# how to NOT match 0s when there isn't a dot exist

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a pattern:

20(.00), for example:

```
$20.00 
$20 
$20.0
```

$ can be replaced by any other currency symbol.

I can be sure that my input for sure contains the symbol at the beginning so i do not need to validate that.

I tried the following regex:

```
([^0-9,\.]+)(20\.?0{0,2})
```

But this also matches:

$2000

So my question is: how do I make this regex stop matching 0 when there is no dot exist.

Comment: Try `(20(\.0{0,2})?)`

Comment: so to be clear you want to match in 200 just 20?  but in 20.00 you want to 20.20?

Comment: Yep, just put the fraction part in a separate capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the entire "dot-num" suffix optional, instead of just the trailing zeroes, and force the regex to match up to the end:

```
([^0-9,\.]+)(20(\.0{0,2})?)$
```

Comment: Why do you use `$` anchor alone without `^` at beginning?

Comment: He said he's sure about the symbol being at the beginning, so there's no  point in adding it (although it wouldn't hurt).

Comment: He would have been sure about ending too if he had the correct regex. i.e. without `$`: `(20(\.0{0,2})?)` right?

Comment: Well, that would still match `$2000` and `$20.50`.

Comment: It doesn't match `$2000` in `$2000` it matches `$20` in `$2000`. So it differs I think?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `+` quantifier otherwise many more things will come through your matching process in addition you should enclose `.` and following zeros in an optional group:

```
^[€$](20(\.0{0,2})?)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjIX5O/1)

or if you are sure about symbol use:

```
^\D(20(\.0{0,2})?)$
```